# Adding large numbers of properties in Core Data, crashing when starting from phone but not from Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to add data to CoreData. It works fine when I build from Xcode to the phone but when I try to start the app directly from iPhone it crashes on first save to the Context.

I read a text file that is synced via iTunes File Sharing, the file is pretty big (~350 000 lines). The values I get from the file is added to two different arrays (barcodes and productNames). The arrays are later batched through and the sent to the function where I save the data.

**From the array loop:**
[...]

```
        words = [rawText componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    int loopCounter = 0;
    int loopLimit = 20000;

    int n = 0;
    int wordType;
    NSEnumerator *word = [words objectEnumerator];  
    NSLog(@"Create arrays");
    while(tmpWord = [word nextObject]) {

        if ([tmpWord isEqualToString: @""] || [tmpWord isEqualToString: @"\r\n"]) {
            //          NSLog(@"%@*** NOTHING *** ",tmpWord);
        }else {



            n++;
            wordType = n%2;

            if (wordType == kBarcode) {
                [barcodes addObject: tmpWord];

            }else if (wordType == kProduct) {
                [productNames addObject: tmpWord];  
            }
            // Send to batch //
            loopCounter ++;

            if (loopCounter == loopLimit) {
                loopCounter = 0;
                NSLog(@"adding new batch");
                [self addBatchOfData];

                [barcodes release];
                [productNames release];

                barcodes = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20000] retain];
                productNames = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20000] retain];


            }

        }
```

[...]

**And then the save-function:**

```
-(void)addBatchOfData {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSError *error;

NSUInteger loopLimit = 5000;
NSUInteger loopCounter = 0;

NSString *ean;  
NSString *designation;

for (int i=0; i<[barcodes count];i++ ) {

    ean = [barcodes objectAtIndex:i];
    designation = [productNames objectAtIndex:i];

    Product *product = (Product *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:importContext];
    [product setDesignation:designation];
    [product setBarcode:ean];

    loopCounter ++;
    if (loopCounter == loopLimit) {
        NSLog(@"Save CoreData");
        [importContext save:&error];
        [importContext reset];
        [pool drain];

        pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        loopCounter = 0;
    }
}
// Save any remaining records
if (loopCounter != 0) {
    [importContext save:&error];
    [importContext reset];
}
[pool drain];
```

}

It's really irritating that it works fine when I build from Xcode. Hopefully there is a setting that I missed or something...

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I don't get passed the Default-screen and I don't have any logs. Can it have something to do with the provisioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offload your file loading in a background thread and let the phone start up your main window and view.  iOS will kill your app if you do not present a view in a timely manor (this is what you are seeing).

I have to do something like this for my xml -> CoreData converter code.  I just present the user with a view notifying them of what is going on and a progress bar (I use https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD).
something like:

```
self.hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:window];

// Set determinate mode
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
hud.delegate = self;
hud.labelText = @"Converting Data File";
[self.window addSubview:hud];

// Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
[hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(convertToCoreDataStoreTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

You just have to make sure that you use a separate NSManagedObjectContext in the new thread.

Comment: Thanks Brent! That's actually how I solved it. I was surprised how easy it was to make a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you implement this delegate method and then try to see what is going on with memory.

when running in the simulator, you have no memory constraints, but when running in the phone you do

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I don't run it in the simulator but I build it to the device. When I do that, it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the solution to my question.

What I was doing was that I started all the heavy data crunch in the "- (void) viewDidLoad {". When I changed it to start the crunch after I clicked a button in the app, it worked just fine.

Right now it's just finding out where the start the data crunch, any suggestions?